# VueJS Подставить определенный текст в input, нажатием на ссылку

Tags: vue.js

знатоки!

Делаю что то типа микроблога, есть пользовательское сообщение с ссылкой "Ответить" и атрибутом data-user, в котором подставлено имя автора текста. При нажатии на "Ответить" хочу поместить имя из атрибута в инпут $(.msg-input), не понимаю, как это сделать.

HTML

```
<a href="#comments-form" v-bind:data-user="comment.user" v-scroll-to="'#comments-form'">Ответить</a>
<input v-model="newComment.text" class="msg-input" type=search name="focus" required placeholder="Напишите что нибудь...">
```

VUE

```
var comments = new Vue({
  el: '#comments',

  data: {
        avatarDefault: 'http://orig07.deviantart.net/4bc8/f/2013/240/2/2/free_avatar_aang_icon_by_zutarart-d6k31hx.gif',
        comments: [
            {
              id: 1,
              user: 'Олег',
              text: 'текст текст текст',
              date: 'Январь 20, 2021',
              time: '11:45' 
            }
        ],

        // Comments form
        newComment: {
          user: 'Валера',
          text: '',
          date: '',
          time: '' 
        },
        
        nextComment: 2 
  },


  methods: {
    clearForm: function () {
      //this.newComment.user = '';
      this.newComment.text = '';
      this.newComment.date = '';
    },
    
    addComment: function () {
      this.comments.push({
        id: this.nextComment++,
        user: this.newComment.user,
        text: this.newComment.text,
        date: moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY'),
        time: moment().format('h:mm a') });

      this.clearForm();
      VueScrollTo.scrollTo('#comments-form'); // scroll to bottom
    },
    
    deleteComment: function () {

    }

    
  } 
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал с помощью jquery

```
$(document).on("click","#answer", function () {
   var clickedBtnID = $(this).attr('data-user');
   $('.msg-input').val(clickedBtnID + ", ");
});
```